How to solve the lock contention performance problem when accessing memory pools created by spdk_mempool_create() with multiple threads
As the title says, I have got a memory pool which is created by spdk_mempool_create(), and i know that is thread-safe. There are many threads which will request space from this pool. When there are too many threads, the problem of lock competition is very serious. And these threads are related to the customer's data IO. So I want to know is there a reasonable optimization plan ? I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me.
I can think of allocating a separate memory pool for each thread, but the memory cost will be very high.

"allocating a separate memory pool for each thread" This is what scalable allocators actually do. You do not need to fully replicate the pool but just a part so some-pools are shared and others a rather private one.

"the memory cost will be very high" There is no free lunch. If you want a fast allocator you need either to write a specific memory pool for specific needs or a generic one using more memory. The most specific ones can generally outperform all clever generic allocators by a large margin. Both in term of execution time, scalability and memory overhead.

A trade-off solution (between memory and time) is to allocate pages in a shared allocator. Pages are private to threads and can be released for other threads to use them later. Multi-level allocators are more versatile but also more complex (especially to debug and profile).

Be aware that malloc already allocate more data than needed on mainstream system (see sbrk allocation). This is to avoid many system calls (for small allocations) and also reduce the saturation of the OS allocator by multiple processes. However, it requires more memory than actually needed and this memory is sometimes not directly released while another process would need it. Thus, this is a good example of trade-off solution.
